# Расширение не появляетсе в "Система" > "Инструменты" Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

Я скачал расширение export/import с офиц., все загрузилось на Opencart,[image: введите сюда описание изображения] но оно не отображается в "инструменты". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В главном меню админки в правом углу есть шестиренка, там очищяется кэш. Потом Расширения->Модификации-> В правом углу есть обновить

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В главном меню админки в правом углу есть шестиренка, там очищяется кэш. Потом Расширения->Модификации-> В правом углу есть обновить

Comment: пожалуйста, внесите информацию в текст ответа, нажав [edit].